# What is this rubber tubing called?

Tags: hvac, drain, pipe, pvc, condensate

What is this rubber looking elbow here called and where can it be purchased? It's the black part that is fastened to the 3/4" pvc using hose clamps.

For some context, this is a condensate drain on an air conditioner. It was very helpful to be able to take it apart while troubleshooting a clog. I'm trying to add an auxiliary drain and need a piece that will do the right angle. I need to the name to find out where to buy it though.

I'd prefer to have a way to take it apart rather than gluing the 3/4" pvc together. I'm not a condensate or hvac expert so I may want to redo it later as well.

[image: The picture with the black rubber looking elbow]

Comment: It looks like they used a section of automotive radiator hose or heater hose of the correct dimension.  The key feature being that the hose is pre-molded to the shape. Using plain hose it is likely to crush or kink in the corner.

Answer (score 1):

This is a low-pressure application, so almost any rubber hose of the correct diameter should work. Measure the plastic tubing outside diameter and look in an auto parts shop for heater hose or radiator hose of that inside diameter. Some radiator hoses have a right-angle bend, and smaller diameter heater hose should be flexible enough to bend without kinking.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Using the search terms "one inch flexible rubber elbow," I find a number of items that match, mostly for one and one-half inch sizes but a few as small as one inch. There doesn't seem to be anything smaller. The photo doesn't show scale very well, but I based my search on my air conditioner drain pipe of 1.5 inch diameter. I suspect you'll find more results without the size constraint.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ITPGMVO) has a selection online as well.

[image: flexible rubber elbow]

Comment: Unfortunately for me, the pvc is 3/4". So this would be too large for me to use. I added that detail to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Condensate drip lines do not strictly need to be glued together. In some places it makes sense to glue them together to prevent the fitting from separating, but in others it makes sense to not use glue for ease of maintenance.

If this is the drip line that enters the pump (and not the discharge side of the pump) then an unglued elbow will be just fine.

Comment: This is the drip line for the condensate that drips off of the coils. That's a good point about just leaving it unglued. There won't be any pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use a hard elbow or tee with an intentional 1-2" gap, and bridge the gap with *straight* rubber couplers. That would provide the ease of maintenance you wisely want to retain.

For instance if you need to add an additional drain, that would be a good way to change the elbow to a tee.